# How to check user inputted decimal separator in the textbox by jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, number-formatting

I have the plugin format number. And i want to *improve* it. If user *inputted one decimal separator* in the textbox , user do not input *"," or "."* in the textbox.

ex: no allow user input 11111,55,,.44..  --> allow user input:11111,5554455

Here my plugin:

```
 $.fn.myPlugin = function(options)
{
    options = $.extend({}, {
        thousands: '.',
        decimal: ','
    }, options);

    this.keyup(function()
    {
        $(this).val(function(el, val)
        {
            val = val.replace(/[^\d.,]/g, '').split(options.decimal);
            val[0] = val[0].replace(options.decimal === '.' ? /,/g : /\./g, '');
            val[0] = val[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, "$1" + options.thousands);
            return val.join(options.decimal);

        });
    });
};
```

Comment: I can understand your example but I can't understand how this relates to your sort of question.

Comment: Hello elcalnrs . I means don't allow to user input 11111,55,,..4 in the textbox. User only input 11111,5545555. Can you help me improve this jquery plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is what you're looking for. Whenever you input more than one period or comma it'll just remove it.

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val(),
        patt = /(,.*?,|\..*?\.)/;
    if (patt.test(value)) { $(this).val(value.slice(0, -1)); }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/t8G2q/4/

Comment: Hello elclanrs the code you wrote above has problem. When i input number in the textbox : 1111111 --> output : 1.111.1 it's not value. Value is true : 1.111.111. I think "slice" having problem. Can you help me fix it ?

Comment: Hi elclanrs you can see demo at http://jsfiddle.net/nangvabien/Eeukx/5/ . You can input some case to test as : 123456789  or 1234567, or 12345678.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get what your looking for, but here's a poorly written example done in a hurry to just show how you can do something like this with iteration:

```
$("#test").on('keyup', function() {
    var V = $(this).val().split(''), A=[], L=V.length;
    for (var i=0; i<L; i++) {
        var E=V[i];
        if (E=='.' && A.indexOf(E)!=-1) {}else{A.push(E);}
        var Q=A.join('');
    }
    $(this).val(Q);
});
```

There's a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/aWXyL/1/) for trying it?

Answer (score 0):

@minh, if you simply want to check that there is only one "," or "." in the inputted number, you can simply do something like:

`val.match(/^\d+([.,]\d+)?$/)`

I may have misunderstood exactly what you want to check for. If so, please post a comment.