# How to find continuous occurance of number in a string using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a mobile number field.I need to implement the validation  that if user enter a number continuously for 5 times it should alert as error.

For example if user enters something like 11111345  or 22222777  it should alert an error.

Comment: Do you think its good idea to restrict like this? Now a days many operators are selling fancy number in auction. So this may not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15688386/4370160 this may answer your question

Comment: You could use *REGEX*

Comment: Can't you use JavaScript. Agreed with invissible though.

Comment: @mmuzahid you can answer that then +1 from my side.

Comment: thank u all for ur quick responses

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variables for that purpose. I don't know if the code works, but you may catch the logic.

```
var window.inputcontrol;
var window.count=0;
$("#yourInput").keyup(function (){

var inputtedNumber;
//get the last character
inputtedNumber = $("#yourInput").val().slice(-1);

if (inputtedNumber===inputcontrol){
//if inputted value is the same holded value 
count= count+1;
} else {
//if inputted value is not the same with holded value, reset counter
inputcontrol=inputtedNumber;
count=0;
}

if (count===5){
alert("your alert");
} 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regex to match exactly 5 consecutive numbers ...

```
/(^|(.)(?!\2))(\d)\3{4}(?!\3)/
```