# How to exlcude grey colour code from the file

Tags: python, html

and parsing a HTML file. But i need to exclude grey color, i did it for black as if now but the grey color have alot of variation to give in if condition may i know how can i use it.

```
if style.find("color")>=0:
        aux = style[style.find("color"):]
        aux = aux[0:aux.find(";") + 1]
        
        if aux.find('#000000') < 0 and aux.find('black') < 0 and aux.find('#000') < 0: 
            use_raw = '%s%s' % (use_raw, aux)
```

This how i am exlcuding black, but here i want to exclude grey too.

Comment: "pure" grey always has the same value for RGB values, you can split the values `000000` into 3 sets of 2 digits, each set for each color, if the 3 sets are equal, you have grey.

Comment: But, in python we are not able to split the value, as it throwing a error, that it should be str

Comment: you can use slices. Strip the `#` and check that `x[:2] == x[2:4] == x[4:]` where x is the hex color.

Comment: regular expression?

Comment: Rachit, did that regex work okay for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can use a regex. `^#([a-fA-F0-9]{1,2})\1\1$` will identify all 6-digit and 3-digit gray hex colors.

---

## Explanation

#### Identifying 'grey'

All grey hex color codes have **3 sets of 2 digits** or **3 identical digits**. e.g. `#151515`, `#1C1C1C`, `#2E2E2E`, `#424242`, `#555`, `#EEE`..... and this is how we can identify them as grey.

#### Determining if string meets 'grey' format

Therefore I would use a regex. The following regular expression will match all strings, that start with a `#`, and contain 3 identical consecutive sets of 2 digit alpha-numeric characters. Hence match all greys.

```
^#([a-fA-F0-9]{1,2})\1\1$
```

#### Applying with Python

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("^#([a-fA-F0-9]{1,2})\1\1$")
pattern.match(aux)
```

See the Python documentation on regular expressions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

#### References:

- http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/gray-color.htm
- [How to find 3 or more consecutive characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688193/how-to-find-3-or-more-consecutive-characters)
- [Check if string matches pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595051/check-if-string-matches-pattern)
- http://www.xcprod.com/titan/XCSB-DOC/hex.html
- [Blender's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464744/blender) comment [about 3-digit hex codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621344/how-to-exlcude-grey-colour-code-from-the-file/43621760#comment74293735_43621760)

Comment: You can change your regex to `^#([a-fA-F0-9]{1,2})\1\1$` and it should work for three-digit colors.

Comment: Didn't think of that, thanks @Blender! I've amended the answer

Comment: Which part isn't working? I need something more specific to be able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do something like

```
    for i in ["lightgray", "lightgrey", "silver", "darkgray", "darkgrey",
            "gray", "grey", "dimgray", "dimgrey", "darkslategrey"]:
        if aux.find(i)<0:
            use_raw = '%s%s' % (use_raw, aux)
    for i in range(1,256):
        if aux.find('#%02x%02x%02x'%(i,i,i))<0 and format(i<<16 | i<<8 | i, '06X')<0 and format(i<<16 | i<<8 | i, '06x')<0:
            use_raw = '%s%s' % (use_raw, aux)
```

You could probably make the code smaller and more efficient, but that's a simple answer, I guess.
(This does include only *strictly* grey colour. It does not allow for slight variations.)

Comment: @RachitAgarwal, the list is to cover all bases. The for function with the range is designed to cover all hexa 3-digit, 6-digit, and RGB colour codes.